# How do I tell if the parent is a tfoot?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I have the following:

```
$('td').click(function(myEvent) {
var local = {
tr:$(this).closest('tr')
};
log(local.tr.parent());
}
```

Q: How do I write something like:

```
if (local.tr.parent() == 'tfoot')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( local.tr.parent().is('tfoot') )
```

check out is() in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: I think I'll accept your answer here because .is() shows my example specifically in the documentation.  Thanks Groovetrain!

Answer (score 3):

```
if( local.tr.parent()[0].nodeName === 'TFOOT' ) { }
```

or

```
if( local.tr.parent().is('tfoot') ) { }
```

---

By the way, you're using a *trailing comma* in your `local` object. Always avoid that in Javascript. IE will screw up because of this.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks!  I cut other code out to simplify the question.  Good catch!